# Is returning Result types the standard way of dealing with errors in Kotlin?

Tags: android, exceptions, kotlin

Given that there are no checked exceptions in Kotlin, are Result types the correct way to indicate an exception occurred to the caller?

For example, I have the following function in my code:

```
suspend fun addUserToSignInHistory(user: User): Result<Unit> {
    return try {
        preferencesStore.edit { preferences ->
            users.add(user.id)
            preferences[USERS_KEY] = users
        }

        Result.success(Unit)
    } catch (t: Throwable) {
        Result.failure(t)
    }
}
```

Given that `edit` may throw an `IOException` or an `Exception` as per the documentation, is this the ideal way of handling this?

Comment: The code you have written is redundant since `runCatching` does the same thing with fewer lines - however I suspect the choice of return type and whether you catch or simply let the exception be handled at a higher level, will be situations so I doubt there is a 'correct' or 'ideal' solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is almost the ideal way of dealing with exceptions in Kotlin. Dealing with the `Result` objects is used very often in Kotlin because it makes it easier to make business logic decisions. On a functional level everything is right about your code. However you can still improve it and so a potentially better approach would be to do this instead, which is very similar, only that we do not explicitly create the `Result` objects and we let Kotlin do that for us:

```
suspend fun addUserToSignInHistory(user: User) = runCatching {
    preferencesStore.edit { preferences ->
        users.add(user.id)
        preferences[USERS_KEY] = users
    }
}
```

But indeed `runCatching` and namely the usage of `Result` is a standard when and if we want to programmatically deal with exceptions.

Comment: Yes, I modified my code after seeing @DavidT's comment. Thank you.